# Avoid "Task not serialisable" with nested method in a class

Tags: apache-spark

I understand the usual "Task not serializable" issue that arises when accessing a field or a method that is out of scope of a closure.

To fix it, I usually define a local copy of these fields/methods, which avoids the need to serialize the whole class:

```js
class MyClass(val myField: Any) { 
  def run() = { 
    val f = sc.textFile("hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file.csv") 

    val myField = this.myField 
    println(f.map( _ + myField ).count) 
  } 
}
```

Now, if I define a nested function in the run method, it cannot be serialized:

```js
class MyClass() { 
  def run() = { 
    val f = sc.textFile("hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file.csv") 

    def mapFn(line: String) = line.split(";") 

    val myField = this.myField 
    println(f.map( mapFn( _ ) ).count) 

  } 
}
```

I don't understand since I thought "mapFn" would be in scope... 
Even stranger, if I define mapFn to be a val instead of a def, then it works:

```js
class MyClass() { 
  def run() = { 
    val f = sc.textFile("hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file.csv") 

    val mapFn = (line: String) => line.split(";") 

    println(f.map( mapFn( _ ) ).count)     
  } 
}
```

Is this related to the way Scala represents nested functions?

What's the recommended way to deal with this issue ? 
Avoid nested functions?

Comment: I am seeing this as well, once they change to val's not defs it works! So thanks for sharing this observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it working in the way so that in the first case `f.map(mapFN(_))` is equivalent to `f.map(new Function() { override def apply(...) = mapFN(...) })` and in the second one it is just `f.map(mapFN)`? When you declare a method with `def` it is probably just a method in some  anonymous class with implicit `$outer` reference to the enclosing class. But `map` requires a `Function` so the compiler needs to wrap it. In the wrapper you just refer to some method of that anonymous class, but not to the instance itself. If you use `val`, you have a direct reference to the function which you pass to the `map`. I'm not sure about this, just thinking out loud...